In the future, rich old people could transfer their conscience into poor young people. What's the name of the movie?
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie and I'm having a hard time doing that.
So the plot is similar with the one described in the title. If I remember right, the poor young people had only a couple of hours per day of living their own life and the rest was taken by the rich old people that couldn't use their own energy to do things.
The protagonist of the movie obviously manages to end this.
I think the movie is about 4-5 years old.
Can anyone help me remember the name of the movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please [edit] in any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

You might be referring to "In time" With Justin Timberlake but I could be wrong

Might be Selfless, a 2015 movie starring
Ben Kingsley and
Ryan Reynolds.

The timeline and most importantly the plot summary match the movie Transfer. It is a German movie from 2010 and it's description on imdb reads:

In a futuristic society where the wealthy get to live forever by swapping bodies with refugees, an elderly couple explores this opportunity with harsh consequences.

If you go and see this trailer there is a mention about the refugees being able to gain control over their bodies only for a few hours at night.

Awesome! Thanks, this seems to be the movie. I didn't even remembered it was German...me and my short memory
